# Apply force to Gazebo model trough ROS2

Tags: gazebo, ros2, simulation

I am setting up some simulation for a project in which a mobile robot need to avoid some moving obstacles. I wrote the logic to control the mobile robot on ROS2 Humble and I am performing the simulation on Gazebo Sim (Gazebo Garden).

I looking for a way to move the obstacles in Gazebo. I found out that I can apply a force to them using the `Apply Force Torque Plugin` from the GUI or by publishing a message to the associated topic. By inspecting the topic, I found out that the message type it uses is `gz.msgs.EntityWrech`, which at first glance is not supported by the `gz_bridge` package for now (it is not listed among the supported message types in [this repository](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/blob/ros2/ros_gz_bridge/README.md)).

Can someone give me some tips on how to proceed?